# C# WPF - Setting Textbox.Text to string doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, string, if-statement, textbox

I have got 3 Textboxes.

- WHRScore
- KFScore
- FettGesamtscore

I want to compare WHRScore and KFScore to eachother, in order to set a new string into FettGesamtscore as Text.
My little Code:

```
if (WHRScore.Equals("+") && KFScore.Equals("-"))
            {
                FettGesamtscore.Text = "Ø";

            }
```

I already have set 2 breakpoints. The first breakpoint fires in the if-clause and works pretty good, but the second breakpoint doesn't fire at FettGesamtscore.Text = "Ø". I dont know why this line is not being executed, maybe you can help me ?

[image]

I have already used the same princip with other code, where it works like a charm. For example in the same window:

```
  if (WHR >= 0.80 && WHR <= 0.84)
                        {

                            WHRScore.Text = "+";
                        }
```

The same for the other textbox..

```
if (fp >= 19.0 && fp <= 20.9)
                            {

                                KFScore.Text = "-";;
                            }
```

As you can see on the picture below, it is working there like a charm.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't you want `WHRScore.Text.Equals("+")` ?  You're using the equality function between a string and a text box object, not it's value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's a simple case of forgetting to specify the property (effectively a typo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would have added as a comment, but not enough rep.

shouldn't you use:

```
if (WHRScore.TEXT.Equals("+") && KFScore.TEXT.Equals("-"))
        {
            FettGesamtscore.Text = "Ø";

        }
```